# Module is not installed in Monorepo

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, storybook, lerna, monorepo

For a new project i am using Lerna and React Storybook. I want to create a monorepo with multiple packages.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
     .babelrc
     .storybook
     package.json
     node_modules
     packages/
       button/
         .babelrc
         node_modules/
         package.json
         index.js
       theme/
         node_modules/
         package.json
         index.js
```

I want to import the theme from the theme package inside my button package, which i install through npm in my button package.

In my button package i am importing the theme

`import theme from '@company/company-theme';`

and i get the following error:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@company/company-theme' in buttonpath`

At first i thought it was a babel problem and in the package.json i installed the following babel packages

```
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
"babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.2",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
```

And in the projectroot and the button root i created a `.babelrc` and added the following code:

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"],
  "env": {
    "dev": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem however still exists. Anyone here knows what to do?

Comment: Note that you have to include the theme package in your dependencies and then run bootstrap, otherwise lerna cannot link it properly.

Comment: Do you mean i have to add it in the package.json dependency on my main project or in the button package. I added it to the package.json inside the button.

Comment: yes, that should be correct. Did you run `lerna bootstrap`? Do you see `company-theme` in button node modules?